# Getting a hardwired connection at a specific location?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, ps3

Okay so my internet is a cable modem which is down the hall from where I have a PS3. I currently have a wireless router setup. My current internet connection is advertised as about 7 [Mbps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Megabit_per_second). However, my PS3 is only getting about 0.98 Mbps. My computer in the same location as my PS3 gets about 14 Mbps

There are no cable outlets in the room where my PS3 is. Running a cable to the room where my PS3 sits is not an option.

How can I get a hardwired connection for my PS3?

---

**EDIT:** I just wanted to give an update describing what solution I went with. I used the shared connection option that [studiohack](https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack) had suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting up a wireless access point somewhere in between your router and your PS3, and which would repeat the wireless signal and make it stronger... A suggestion @ Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Linksys-WAP54G-Wireless-G-Access-Point/dp/B00007KDVJ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007KDVJ)

OR: Not sure how this would work, but you could set up another router (wireless) in the same room as your PS3, and run an ethernet cable from the wireless router to your PS3...

OR: you can "share" your computer's internet connection with your PS3...If it is a desktop, that is tricky, but if it is a laptop, you can share it via wired or wireless...

A couple of ideas...hope that helps!

Comment: @Lucas: see updated answer.  any more questions, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Okay I forgot about sharing the internet connection. Do you know how I would set that up on my PS3? I'm pretty sure I remember how to do it on my computer (Ubuntu).

Comment: I don't think you would have to do anything on the PS3's end, just set it up on your Ubuntu computer, and see what happens.  In theory, it should just work as if you plugged the PS3 into the wall...